# Jolt Transform JSON Spec for List JSON Input

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to do a JOLT shift transformation of an inputted JSON-list
Below my input:

```json
[
  {
    "number": 1001,
    "description": "KA01"
  },
  {
    "number": 1002,
    "description": "KA02"
  }
]
```

And I want to create this output:

```
{
  "actions" : [
    {
      "_type": "SetFieldValue",
      "fieldName": "UUID",
      "value": "uuid"
    },
    { "_type": "InsertRow" },
    {
      "_type": "SetFieldValue",
      "fieldName": "number",
      "value": "1001"
    },
    {
      "_type": "SetFieldValue",
      "fieldName": "description",
      "value": "KA01"
    },
    { "_type": "InsertRow" },
    {
      "_type": "SetFieldValue",
      "fieldName": "number",
      "value": "1002"
    },
    {
      "_type": "SetFieldValue",
      "fieldName": "description",
      "value": "KA02"
    },
    {
      "_type": "SetFieldValue",
      "fieldName": "start"
    }
  ]
}
```

I haven´t done much with JOLT transformation and need help in this case.

Comment: Ah yes thank you. There was a typo in there. But also yes the input is complete, that´s why  I need to create a lot around my input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can divide the JSON value into parts by key names and values, and then add `_type` attributes as being default such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&1.[&2].fieldName",
          "@": "&1.[&2].value"
        }
      },
      "#UUID": "x[#2].fieldName",
      "#uuid": "x[#2].value",
      "#start": "y[#2].fieldName"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "_type": "SetFieldValue"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": ""
      },
      "#InsertRow": "_type"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort",
    "spec": {}
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: That helped a lot. Thanks

Comment: you're welcome @franzbauer